# Can we use tenses as we normally do to tell the listener the timings of the imaginary events?

Tags: grammar, tense, subjunctives, imaginary-situations

When we talk about an imaginary scenario, can we use tenses as we normally do to tell the listener the timings of the imaginary events?

By the way, do different subjects like those in the examples (**a person** and **I**) affect anything regarding tense use and grammar (I mean, anything else from the subject-verb agreement)?

---

Example 1 is using present tense to indicate the imaginary present and past tense to indicate the imaginary past.

Example 1:

My friend: What are you doing?

Me:

> (Telling my friend an imaginary scenario) A person **meets** a beautiful girl. He **is talking** to her. Two days ago, they once **met** at a library. She **was reading** a book. He **didn't** know what the book **was** about. Now it **seems** like they **can hang out** because a moment ago, he **found** that she **was reading** a book he likes. They **will have** a lot to talk about.

---

Example 2 is using past subjunctive mood to indicate the different timings.

Example 2:

My friend: What are you doing?

Me:

> (Telling my friend an imaginary scenario) I **met** a beautiful girl. I **(was or were?) talking** to her. Two days ago, we **had met** at a library. She **had been reading** a book. I **hadn't known** what the book **had been** about. Now it **seemed** like we **could hang out** because a moment ago, I just **had found** that she **had been reading** a book I like. We **would have** a lot to talk about.

Comment: You should remove the first "meets" or "met" - I think that is confusing. Without that it is easier to understand what is going on. You could start by saying "He is talking to a beautiful girl." and "I was talking to a ..."

Comment: So you are suggesting that without the first "meets" and "mets", the rests are ok, right? Even the original examples are correct but just somewhat unnatural, right?

Comment: Your imaginary situation is not answer to "What are you doing?". You could reply, "I am meeting a beautiful girl" or "I have just met a beautiful girl". You have to express somehow that the situation is imaginary, though. It isn't clear without context.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I phrased it like that on purpose. How about adding two sentences to the original examples to make the context more clear: 
My friend: What are you talking about? The girl thing?
Me: I was imagining things. Don't mind me.

Comment: @vincentlin I think one change you should make at the outset is turn "What are you doing?" to "What are you thinking?". To get to the errors in the actual content, you need to fix other errors that make it hard to understand the question.

Comment: I would probably just leave them like that because in my case, my friend can't always know if I am thinking about something or not. Rather, they are likely to just casually ask, "what are you doing?" So, leaving the examples like that makes the situation more "real" in a way, I think. And If other learners can learn from this question, they will be able to take the grammar rules learnt and apply to other easier and more standard contexts. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These "imaginary scenes" sound like blurbs publishers post inside dust jackets on books and elsewhere. Example 1 is fine except for this one sentence:

> Two days ago, they once met at a library.

I think you mean: They met once at a library.

"They once met..." gives the impression that at some point in the past they met. "They met once..." gives the impression that they met only once, not twice or several times.

The tenses are fine.

I would edit Example 2.

> I met a beautiful girl. I was talking to her.

Say "was" rather than "were" because "was" is singular and goes with "I." "I" is also singular.

> Two days ago, we had met at a library. She had been reading a book. I
>   hadn't known what the book was about.

I changed "had been" to "was" in "I hadn't known what the book had been about." You don't need "had been" twice in that sentence; it's too convoluted and "doubles over" the past tense.

> Now it seemed like we could hang out because a moment ago, I just
>   found that she had been reading a book I like. We would have a lot to
>   talk about.

I removed "had" from "I just had found that she had been reading..." This is another case of "doubling over."

NOTE: I am not sure of the proper grammar terms; I base my answer on lifelong use of the English language, including advanced degree in the arts and humanities.

Comment: Thank you for your to-the-point answer. It really clears up my confusion. Hope you have a good day^^

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score -1):

It is not a case of as you have called them *imaginary situations*, if we take your examples into consideration. Such case is embraced in such section of the grammar as *stories, commentaries and instructions*.
Present tenses are often used informally to tell stories. The simple present is used for the events – the things that happen one after another. The present progressive is used for ‘background’ – things that are already happening when the story starts, or that continue through the story.
Such style requires the observance of some rules that have been in breach with in your examples.

Comment: Would you be more precise about the rules broken? Maybe you can teach me how to tell an imaginary scenario that have several timings, because things can happen at different times, right?

Comment: I am sorry. You had time for studying the qualitative answer on the same topic carefully which you recieved several years ago. My aim was to call your attention to the name of your topic in the grammar theory.  I hope my answer will be useful for the readers of the site. https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/149420/tense-usage-in-an-imaginary-discussion

Comment: Yes, I have checked that answer. However, the scenarios in that question are continuous. This time, the situations involve different timings, including imaginary past events, and I wonder how to express the idea and distinguish them from the imaginary present events. That is why I asked this question with the complicated examples. The question might seem the same to you, but for a learner, she can be thinking the two questions differently. Anyway, thanks for your information. If you have time, would you answer this question in your way?

Comment: The style that I have mentioned looks approximately as it follows:Look. Listen. Something interesting happens to me. That gal. It seems to me that I fell for her. This was so.  I meet a beautiful girl. I talk to her. Two days ago, we meet each other in a library. She is reading a book there. I don't know what the book is about. It seems like we can hang out because of our behaviour a moment ago. It comes down to me that she is reading. I like, 'We have a lot to talk about.'

Comment: Is that historical present method you're using? Because "Two days ago, we MEET each other in a library" and the following in present tense doesn't make sense to me. Maybe I am at a too basic level to correctly interpret it. Maybe I should start a new question thread for this....

Comment: No. It's an informal speech that  is used frequently. It has been described in the current grammars. It is necessary just to switch on TV showing a sports reportage from the UK, for example, to make sure. I don't think a new thread is necessary here. I called the way this chapter is titled in many grammars of Advanced English.

Comment: It's nothing wrong with your guestions. Pls, go on. But, I am afraid that moderator shall ask us to stop the discussion in the short commentaries part of the page. It is contrary to the regulations of the site.  The part with *stories, commentaries and instructions* starts from *I meet a beautiful girl.*

Comment: Ok, I have checked the chapter about "stories, commentaries and instructions." (link: reurl.cc/7XlZpk) Then, isn't it a little off with your example: "That gal. It seems to me that I FELL for her." The past tense in it tells the listener that that event happens earlier in the imaginary scene. So, why can't we just use past tense for things happening earlier that way since we certainly needs them to tell the past events? Is it because using present tense is more lively? If so, doesn't that mean using past tense is not wrong? Sorry for so many questions. Just curious about it.

Comment: The previous post was originally the reply to kngram's "No. it's an informal speech..." I accidentally deleted it. Fortunately, I had backed it up, so I posted it again. I hope it serves as a reference for other learners.

Comment: The text begins with a past tense verbal group, which sets up the reference time for the story - it happened in the past, when the speaker visited the library. The next finite verbal groups use present tense, as they describe the layout of what happened in the library at the time of that meeting with the girl.The initial verbal phrases of the text set up the time reference of the story by providing background information (orientation) that the listener needs to understand the story that follows.

Comment: It is impossible to unscrew why it is so in some logical manner. These are conventions and rules of the informal vocal speech in the UK for some contexts, which have developed spontaneously over many, many years and have been described by language scholars.